# Windows 7 is not detecting logitech USB mouse

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, logitech-mouse

Yesterday, my old Microsoft IntelliMouse died. I bought a new Logitech USB mouse with a cable (no wireless) and connected it to my PC. Unfortunately, Windows 7 does not detect it.

I have tried to connect an external hard drive to the same port and could access it, so I do not believe the usb port is the issue.
The laser (i.e. red light) under the mouse is off.
The new mouse did not come with drivers to install, manual says to plug it in while the computer is on, it will detect it.
I googled this issue and found out I had to remove the IntelliMouse driver, which I did and rebooted my PC.
More Googling suggested to launch the 'add a device' feature, which I did, but the screen is stalling:

Comment: It should "just work".  Try it in another computer, if it behaves the same way, the mouse is defective..

Comment: If the laser is off, it still could be be a USB port *power* issue, since some external HDD have their own power supplies. Have you tried other ports?